# Oracle connection using Ole DB and ODBC

Tags: delphi

Im trying to make a 32bit oracle connection on a Windows 10 machine using ADO in Delphi 11.2.

For Ole DB I use this connection string:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=[HOST])(PORT=[PORT]))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=[SID])(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User ID=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];
```

and for ODBC I use this connection string:

```
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=[HOST])(PORT=[PORT]))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=[SID])(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User ID=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];
```

I want to use the second connection (ODBC) because a lot of old programs use this to connect to Oracle and I dont want to recompile and change the old code.

My problem is that the OLE DB connection works fine, but the ODBC connection gives a "[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019." error.

I can also see it tries to resolve the "{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}" to a MSDASQL provider for the ODBC connection.

Now comes the wierd part.

If I do a simple ADO connection to oracle DB using the OLE DB Connection, then disconnect and then connect using the ODBC connection, then it works fine and connect - until I restart the program.

For connection I use this simple Delphi code using ADO

```
    ADO := TADOConnection.Create(Nil);
    Try
      ADO.ConnectionString := ConnectionStr;
      ADO.LoginPrompt := False;
      Try
        Try
          ADO.Connected := True;
          if ADO.Connected then
            MessageBox(0, Pchar('Connected to Database.' + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + 'Using Provider: ' + ADO.Provider + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + 'Connection String:' + sLineBreak + ConnectionStr + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + 'Used Conncetions String:' + sLineBreak + ADO.ConnectionString), Pchar('Connected'), MB_OK+MB_ICONINFORMATION);
          Result := True;
        Except
          On E: Exception do
            raise Exception.Create('Failed to connect.' + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + 'Using Provider: ' + ADO.Provider + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + 'Connection String:' + sLineBreak + ConnectionStr + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + 'Used Conncetions String:' + sLineBreak + ADO.ConnectionString + sLineBreak + SLineBreak + 'Error:' + sLineBreak + E.Message);
        end;
      Finally
        if ADO.Connected then
          ADO.Connected := False;
      end;
    Finally
      ADO.Free;
    end;
```

I suspect the OLE DB initialize something that makes the ODBC connection possible. If I do it the other way around and try to connect to the ODBC first and then the OLE DB, then is gives a "Catastrophic failure." exception.

Anyone have an idea why my ODBC connection is not working (without the wierd OLE DB "hack") ?

Comment: The error is telling you that an error (ORA-01019) has occurred, but it couldn't read the DLL that contains the textual description of that error. Solve the ORA-01019 problem, and your current error will go away.

Comment: Relevant information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27948022/62576

Comment: The link referende to MSDAORA.dll which is deprecated, this the MSDASQL which is very much alive, its just not very clear on MS. Pages. But look here. MSDASQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-odbc?view=sql-server-ver16, MSDAORA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver16